# Logging in map reduce using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Is it possible to use print() statements to log the output from map reduce javascript functions?
I know how to do it using mongodb but using pymongo in python script, how to do it?

Comment: You can us `print somevalue` in the script - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958195/mongodb-print

Comment: But where to see the output of this print statement?

Comment: Check out [a similar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963483/how-to-get-print-output-for-debugging-map-reduce-in-mongoid) - it doesn't depend on the driver since hte map/reduce functions are run on the server and are always javascript.